# I want to display data out of JSON

Tags: javascript, json

If I had a JSON object formatted like this:

```
{ 
    "CampaignID":5918,
    "CampaignFolder":"http://www.Dan.com/campaign/5918-18D/",
    "TargetUser.CampaignID":5918,
    "TargetUser.GUID":"3dbe24a8-a3e3-4de9-86ab-4940c8e148cc",
}
```

Once I grab the object and I want to display an alert with a property, I can use alert(CampaignID) and it correctly displays 5918. But if I try alert(TargetUser.CampaignID) it fails. Any ideas?

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name he's using JS

Answer (score 1):

The way the object is structured, you're going to need to use bracket notation to access those fields. The object key is "TargetUser.CampaignID" but the JS you're using: `TargetUser.CampaignID` means access the `object` `TargetUser` and access its property `CampaignID` when really you just want `"TargetUser.CampaignID"` as a string key.

Try something like this

```js
var data = { 
    "CampaignID":5918,
    "CampaignFolder":"http://www.Dan.com/campaign/5918-18D/",
    "TargetUser.CampaignID":5918,
    "TargetUser.GUID":"3dbe24a8-a3e3-4de9-86ab-4940c8e148cc",
};
alert(data["TargetUser.CampaignID"]);
alert(data["TargetUser.GUID"]);
// data["TargetUser.CampaignID"] is NOT data.TargetUser.CampaignID
// that would look like this: {TargetUser: {CampaignID: 0}}
// not {"TargetUser.CampaignID": 0}
```

:

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to access properties of object in js

1. Dot notation and
2. Bracket notation.

With **Dot** notation -

```
property must be a valid JavaScript identifier. For example, 
object.$1 is valid, while object.1 is not.
```

With **Bracket** notation -

```
property_name is a string or Symbol. It does not have to be a 
valid identifier; it can have any value, including 1foo, !bar!, or 
even " " (a space) or a . (dot character)
```

**See MDN**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors